# How To Check Specific URL Pattern Via PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am confused about how to check my desired URL pattern in php. I want to check `http://XXXXXX.blogspot.com/` pattern that Is my inserted URL has the right URL pattern? `XXXXXX` in the URL can contain any chracters/numbers/dashes or anything that a URL can use. Rest I want the same pattern every time like `http://` in start and `.blogspot.com/` in the end. No more characters before and after it.

For that I am using below code but its not working. So anything wrong in this code?

```
$url = "http://"+[.*]+".blogspot.com/";
if (!$url){
echo "URL Pattern Didnt Match.";
} else {
echo "URL Pattern Matched.";
}
```

Comment: Please read up on preg_match. Your code doesn't seem to use the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script produces an error. You would do:

```
$url = "http://(.+?)\.blogspot\.com/";
if (!preg_match("~$url~", $str)){
    echo "URL Pattern Didnt Match.";
} else {
    echo "URL Pattern Matched.";
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why people down vote the question. If asker knows all then why to ask here... :p

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Some people do not understand your question but don't mind your question is not good. People has different different mind and your question is Good one and `stackoverflow` made for asking question.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan downvotes are because of, this type of question was asked n number of times. A simple search will give you the answer. But You failed to do that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj PHP officially give tutorial and like same all other things that we are using official give there all tutorials then Whats this for?

Comment: oh, it's because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175496/how-to-check-specific-url-pattern-via-php/26175533?noredirect=1#comment41039454_26175496

Comment: Don't argue with me . I just explained why your question receive downvotes but i actually didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

- There are many problems in your regex that need to be corrected
- You cannot just test the regex without calling any PHP function like `preg_match`

You can use this code:

```
if (preg_match('#https?://[^.]+\.blogspot\.com/#i', $inputUrl)) {
   echo "URL Pattern Matched.";
} else {
   echo "URL Pattern Didn't Match.";       
}
```